# Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMEventTarget.dispatchEvent]

Tags: javascript, swfaddress

I am very new to javascript, so forgive me for my ignorance.

I am currently using SWFAddress to build deeplinking for a flex application. The problem is that the browser history functionality does not work in IE9.

I would like to fix that, and it seems like it shouldn't be a difficult fix.

When I debug the script in firefox, I get this error message:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIDOMEventTarget.dispatchEvent]
this.dispatchEvent(new SWFAddressEvent(type));
```

This points to this bit of code as the culprit:

```
_dispatch = function(type) {
            this.dispatchEvent(new SWFAddressEvent(type));
            type = type.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + type.substr(1);
            if(typeof this['on' + type] == FUNCTION)
                this['on' + type]();
        },
```

I have checked and confirmed that the SWFAddressEvent object is instantiated correctly without any problems.

The problem seems to lie here:

```
this.dispatchEvent = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
        if (this.hasEventListener(event.type)) {
        console.log(event);
            event.target = this;
            for (var i = 0, l; l = _listeners[event.type][i]; i++)
                l(event);
            return TRUE;           
        }
        return FALSE;
    };
```

It seems that for some reason, `dispatchEvent` does not receive the `SWFAddressEvent` that was created.

Can someone explain what that error message means? And why is it that when the page first loads, it is able to dispatch 3 events properly, but when it comes to dispatching further events, it seems to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the problem is the reference to `this` in:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new SWFAddressEvent(type));
```

This part is executed in an event handler so this is not `SWFAddress`, but `Window`.

I replaced it with `SWFAddress.dispatchEvent(new SWFAddressEvent(type));` and that fixed it - hover I am not a JS expert.

The first three event are generated in a different way than the one that creates `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE`.

Comment: I have stopped using swfaddress and flash to develop rich web applications many months ago, so I can not comment as to whether this fix will work. However, I will mark this answer as correct. If someone comes along in the future with a better answer, then I will mark that as correct :)